# Toggle visibility of list using hover state

Tags: list, forms, vue.js, hover

I am trying to get the list items to populate when I hover over the clear list items represented by the class="show". It was working prior to adding the checklistItems in the html and script section, which was needed in order to solve the issue of the form not being submitted. The form submits but now I'm unable to hover over the clear liquids text to populate the list items information. I'm not sure what I did to cancel out that functionality.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">

<div class="todo-section">
        <input type="checkbox" id="todo7" name="todo7" v-model="checklistItems[6].checked" :value="checklistItems[6].name">
        <label for="todo7" class="checked">You may have <span class="show" style="color:#0000ff; font-weight:bold;">clear liquids</span> <b>UP UNTIL 4 HOURS</b> to scheduled surgery time.</label>
         <ul class="liquid-list">
                <h4>ACCEPTABLE - CLEAR LIQUIDS</h4>
                  <p>1. Water, plain or flavored; Standard or sparkling</p>
                  <p>2. Drinks made from powdered drink mixes (such as Kool Aid or Crystal Light)</p>
                  <p>3. Fruit juices (apple or grape)</p>
                  <p>4. Lemonade no pulp</p>
                  <p>5. Carbonated beverages</p>
                  <p>6. Sports drinks</p>
                  <p>7. Tea or coffee WITHOUT creamer (No non-dairy creamer substitutes)</p>
              </ul>
      </div>
</form>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "CheckList",

  data() {
    return {
      checklistItems: [
        {
          checked: false,
          name: "Clear Liquids",
        },  
      ],
    }; 
  },
 computed: {
    allCheckboxesAreChecked() {
      return this.checklistItems.every((item) => item.checked);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.show {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted;
}

.liquid-list{
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  bottom: 17%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  }

.liquid-list::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 100%;
  border: 15px solid;
  border-color:  #000 #0000 #0000 #0000;
}

.show:hover .liquid-list {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

I was expecting to use :hover to display the popup text information. I also tried it on different classes to see if selector was actually working.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to set a variable that can toggle the visibility of the list. Using events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on the text you want to hover you can toggle the variable, and then conditionally render the list with v-if or [v-show](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-show) based on the variable value (I would prefer v-show for conditional hover text)

```html
<label for="todo7" class="checked">
  You may have 
  <span 
    style="color:#0000ff; font-weight:bold;"
    @mouseenter="showList = true" 
    @mouseleave="showList = false">
    clear liquids
  </span>
  <b>UP UNTIL 4 HOURS</b> to scheduled surgery time.
</label>
<ul class="liquid-list" v-show="showList">
  ...
</ul>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    showList: false,
    ...
  }
}
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNq1Vutu2zYUfpUDDQUSIJZzD6A4xlw3w7wZaZY46Ia6GCjpyGZCiRxJOTaKvPsOqYsVrygGFNEPm5fDjx/P/WswUipclRhEwcBirgSzOJwXg0zqHFhiuSyu5kG/Gv2t2AJDtVTzgGTmBcAg5StIBDOGpKxMZc+gF/USQN+AF6q0YDcKSSRZYvIUy/U8AJ7WRy5oUrDcbTfTVS+XKYrmgODGToid+Xz+JfQrmJJUtGKibFFfCTm8LQXBYhRAT+pc0ZBu4WphgL9kCTnbwJKtEJrFgVGsaGcAxm6Ev1oKqaOfDunLsku6o7C9Z+SLpY1iKdLLebA983MuS4NYWHREzFI+T4kzXIHVJbHtoFeSAonBa8mMCbN9mPsSktIg+D8lT03Ltu/otlKDePhwCw83s8kUTuHXjw9394N+PAQrwdD701JgCqbUC9QbsDzHsFZc32uuUWMpWq1V9/Wczr25HMUO0w7DwfJ0OBqPr29no/fTa+jBeHo9uoPp5I+HyQeiQdutqBoehfCJPFAfAHkiL0BqyARbSY3pJdxbVqRMp26V3qfJ5MVi0FddgOMQPmhePBkyYYqQaZmDks8pEgKkbgdyvkYDe6ZMlsAM/C6lgBH3qGO9MZYJmDoD7u9An4Twiy65hceSJw6BKSXQHVtopnBX/DSEKeaycDQKCaoUakfiLIQx0zGJWCIX4wo1xZfZkToP4V5JbU1Ff3f7IoQZMscikVmGCJ8mM7LwDBKNFAQa9m4k3V/0UsbJus2qKWNjuS0tmg7xQb+srD3oU2C7PNB3icAPOtmBpibRXFka49qRgxQzVgoLX91pF30RzIOxi63KHw6qfJEyy/b2KykAjbbURTOjoKrdJ6r8nM7UPv4qviP4vHX/9mwrh+nucfe1lHy4TKtwOfK8GpGXzviHYI/fBvbkbWBP3wb27G1gz98GlirCN2G/1KOXS5+dq41E5lTSHHp7JxPCOzuVNjQjjX6C6dbVO+5ul9xUVax16dDF/mZvj9NkH66G4AZNpdu/bCAaXu7/hVYpzTdh6ELSlSQahi6MqnuVNNxV44juptjlK/RYSakNVS3a5q4Y+bVYakqSvVhaK/MIjtUaUhpT3qW7HH7Yyfk74Cw2UpBGPJDAjAL49PBdDVvhHV1Uc6tZYVxOiaqhyyh/7vXODt9Vz4xZ8rTQsizSXlVawdXWinU9z6jQdhhrlvKSksLxoVr79f+wjaIY6UqsdJJQiaYa7FxgHvgD/+shVip6xWH7LHc3LZyRnugMd2pqKdVMPXX/8+q3UijZztsrOAisIU4ZX4SPRhbUiHmarrXIFReoPypHzsyD1t/mAfmbfP7Nr7nmofaLupv5xvqjoZbLPflWo0G9oh6i3bOMCj+laLd9fX+D6ypdV5vUh1F38N3NO/RK802fE3tPxiPaHTnPdpK7QkEVe2au12QB0zzKdz9tcM0D6kbH33n6lu5JeFLb+yV4+RdfRlLh)